# What does the { get } mean with UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, swift

```
var moreNavigationController: UINavigationController { get }
```

What does the {get} mean in the above? This is for iOS (in this example this is for Swift). I understand that var is to define a variable; `moreNavigationControl` is for tabBarControllers and is displayed automatically by the `UITabBarController` as needed. Lastly, the `UINavigationController` is the type or Class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**get (means Gettable property)**

It means you can get this the variable only. You can not set its value.

Gettable and settable properties are indicated by writing { get set } after their type declaration, and gettable properties are indicated by writing { get }.

Generally you will see this in protocol declaration.

For. eg.

```
protocol TestProtocol: AnyObject {
  var newVar: String { get }  // <---Gettable only
  var otherVar: Bool { get set }  //<----- can be Gettable/settable the value 
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry - can you rephrase that and/or provide an example? "you can get this the variable" is not clear to me

Comment: Ok got it. Is this optional to include?

Comment: see edited answer

Comment: yes, it is. it is up to you. like if you want the variable to be ready only then you can use it {get}

Comment: In the documentation it says: ...The More view controller cannot be customized or selected and does not appear in any of the view controller lists managed by the tab bar controller. It appears automatically when it is needed and is separate from your custom content. 

Are you saying 'read only' refers to the fact that it cannot be customized (i.e. modified and it shows up automatically)

Comment: It doesn't mean read only, it means "at least readable". There could also be a setter defined for `newVar`, just as there could be `func someRandomUnrelatedFunction()`, but that doesn't matter. The protocol is simply requiring for there to be a getter for `newVar`.

Comment: okay..understood.I took it another way. Answer edited!! Thanks